# Criar programa de multiplicação por soma sucessiva em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, soma

As exigências são: resolver números positivos e negativos;  Fazer duas vezes o um milhão, nunca um milhão de vezes o 2, ou seja, sempre o menor número de somas; usar o try e pedir nova execução.

Como estou tentando fazer:

```
import math
L=('s')
while (L=='s'):
 while True:
   try:
    a=int(input('Digite um número: '))
    break
   except: print ('Número inválido. Use um número inteiro.')
 while True:
   try:
    b=int(input('Digite outro número: '))
    break
   except: print ('Número inválido. Use um número inteiro.')

 if (a>0 and b>0) or (a<0 and b<0):
   if abs(a)>=abs(b):
     x=0
     y=0
     for x in range(x,abs(b),1): 
      y=y+a
     print ('O produto entre',a,'e',b,'é igual:',abs(y))
   else:
     x=0
     y=0
     for x in range(x,abs(a),1):
      y=y+b   
     print ('O produto entre',a,'e',b,'é igual:',abs(y))
 else:
   if abs(a)>=abs(b):
     x=0
     y=0
     for x in range(x,abs(b),1): 
      y=y+a
     print ('O produto entre',a,'e',b,'é igual:',-abs(y))
   else:
     x=0
     y=0
     for x in range(x,abs(a),1):
      y=y+b   
     print ('O produto entre',a,'e',b,'é igual:',-abs(y))

 L = input('Se deseja continuar digite s:')
```

Comment: Aqui não é lugar pra pedir que resolva sua lição de casa

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você tornou o processo complicado demais tentando resolver todos os itens de uma vez só. O resultado disso é um código sujo, com muita repetição de lógica que tem todo o potencial para não funcionar; ao invés disso, por que não reduzir seu problema em problemas menores e resolvê-los reparadamente? Aliás, isso é o que chamamos de unidades de código, caso queira pesquisar mais.

1) Você irá precisar ler do usuário um número inteiro e solicitar novamente até que ele entre com um valor válido. Crie uma função para isso:

```
def read_int_until_valid(message: str) -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print('Valor inválido, por favor insira um número inteiro')
```

2) Você precisará realizar a multiplicação entre dois números realizando apenas a soma, então faça uma função para isso:

```
def multiply_with_sum(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    a_positive = (a >= 0)
    b_positive = (b >= 0)
    result_positive = (a_positive == b_positive)

    a = abs(a)
    b = abs(b)

    lowest = min([a, b])
    biggest = max([a, b])

    multiply = sum(biggest for _ in range(lowest))

    return multiply if result_positive else -multiply
```

3) Você precisará de uma função que lê as entradas do usuário e passe-as para a função que calcula a multiplicaçãom então:

```
def read_input_and_multiply():
    a = read_int_until_valid('Valor de a:')
    b = read_int_until_valid('Valor de b:')

    result = multiply_with_sum(a, b)

    print(f'O produto {a}x{b} vale {result}')
```

4) Finalmente, você quer executar isso em um laço infinito, então:

```
def loop():
    while True:
        read_input_and_multiply()

        answer = input('Digite [s] se deseja continuar: ')

        if answer != 's':
            break
```

E, assim, bastará chamar a função `loop()` para a mágica acontecer. Veja funcionando em https://python-multiplicando-atraves-da-soma.acwoss.repl.run.